# How to check Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS grace period remaining days

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop-services

How do I check for remaining days of Remote Desktop Services grace period if the server is also a Domain Controller (so I cannot logon as local admin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct answer**:

Logon to your server as an administrator
Start--All Programs--Accessories--Right-Click on Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator

Enter the following command:

> wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\TerminalServices PATH
>   Win32_TerminalServiceSetting WHERE (__CLASS !="") CALL
>   GetGracePeriodDays

Comment: This copy of server 2008 R2 is already activated. I am not speaking about Server 2008 evaluation period, but Remote Desktop Service grace period.

Comment: Does not work. It returns: ERROR: Description = Invalid namespace

Comment: This does indeed work. The command was failing because there should have been a double backslash after "namespace:"

Comment: It is correct now.  If you copy and paste the above command into a command prompt that is running with Administrator elevation on your Remote Desktop server, it will work.  If not, let me know precisely what error you're receiving.

Answer (score 4):

to do this in PowerShell v2.0 you can use the following single line command:

```
(Invoke-WmiMethod -PATH (gwmi -namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -class win32_terminalservicesetting).__PATH -name GetGracePeriodDays).daysleft
```

Comment: Also works on Server 2012 R2.